# How to save environment variables to file

Tags: bash

Using a terminal I go ahead and declare the environment variable `MY_VARIABLE`

```
MY_VARIABLE=MY_VALUE
```

Next, I want to save the value of this variable to the file:

```
CMD="""cat <<EOF > test.txt
$MY_VARIABLE 
EOF"""
"""
```

and then running:

```
${CMD}
```

I am getting error.

```
cat: <<EOF: No such file or directory
cat: >: No such file or directory
cat: EOF: No such file or directory
```

How to fix the problem?

Comment: Why are you also trying to store the command in a string with what appears to be python-style triple quotes?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But the goal is to save the environment variable value to a file and not to set it.

Comment: @jordanm Please post the solution/fix as an answer so we could up vote it.

Comment: `MY_VARIABLE=MY_VALUE; echo "$MY_VARIABLE" > test.txt`

Comment: Se [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) -- code should not be stored as strings. Code should be stored as functions, or simple command lines (in which no elements are expected to be parsed as code) can be stored as arrays. Though I don't know why you're trying to *store* this code at all, as opposed to just running it.

Comment: @alphanumeric, yes, the goal is to write the value to a file *when your code is run*, but why are you storing the code in a string variable *before you run it*? You can't do that in any other language (python, javascript, etc) without using `eval`; same's true in the general case here (and `eval` has [serious security issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) when the original value is not fully controlled).